# How to have powershell command output not suppressed from console when the output is piped?

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell command

```
c:\path\to\exectuable.exe -param1 -param2 | Where-Object { $_ -match 'pattern' } | ForEach-Object { $output = $output + $_ }
```

The problem with the above is that, it is suppressing the console output of the executable. I understand the output is piped, I additionally want it to be written to the console like it would if it wasn't piped. How do I do that?

Comment: If you want to save and keep the output, use `tee-object`.

Comment: Or you can use -OutVariable to see and store it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Where-Object {write-host $_; $_ -match 'pattern' }
```